# Craft 3.1 Deleting Anything Renders CMS Unresponsive

Tags: craft3

I have a Craft install setup on a LAMP Digital Ocean droplet - everything has been configured to the install requirements.

Yesterday I started having issues with not being able to delete entries, sections, categories - basically anything in the CMS. I noticed there was an update from 3.0.47 to 3.1.0, I updated hoping that would solve my issue but it has not. I looked through the php and apache error logs though there's nothing helpful there.

Clicking the delete button on anything makes the CMS go unresponsive for 3 minutes or so and then it reloads the webpage with no changes. I'm at a loss for what to do next as there's no console log errors or php/apache errors.

Comment: Going to leave this up just in case someone has the same issue I did and needs the obvious answer. Craft uses popups to confirm deleting entries or categories, and Safari and Chrome (at least my settings) block popups. So the site goes unresponsive and reloads the page. Turn on popups for the url and you're good to go.

Comment: Welcome to Craft CMS Stack Exchange Please add your comment as an answer to your question and mark it as answered 